# MariaDB Select into syntax error int a trigger

Tags: mysql, mariadb

I am trying to write a trigger, and I have some syntax errors.
When I insert the code below into trigger, I got the error. But I input it directly, it's ok, why?

```
Select max(User_IDNum) into @IDnum from Users;
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ga534.png)

```
Create trigger IN_Users 
before insert On Users
For each row 
Begin
Select max(User_IDNum) into @IDnum from Users;//syntax error
Set @num = cast(right(@IDnum,2) as int) + 1;
Set @date = Date_format(Now(), '%y%m%d');
set New.User_IDNum = @date + right(‘00’+cast(@num as varchar) , 2);//syntax error
end;
```

Could you help me? I'm new to MariaDB.

Thanks!

Comment: I don't see any evidence that you are setting delimiters https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/stored-programs-defining.html and you cannot cast to varchar. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/cast-functions.html#function_cast

Comment: It would help a lot if you could add the actual syntax error message(s) you are getting, and the MariaDB version you are using (as FOR EACH ROW does not exist in all versions), otherwise this is just a blind educated guessing game.